# LTI and common cartridge

Tags: lti, blackboard, common-cartridge

I am using Blackboard LMS and I am new with LTI staff. I want to know what is common cartridge & how it is related with LTI? Please also specify what are the differences between those?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

LTI (Learning Tools Interoperability) is used commonly in LMS (Education tools) like Blackboard or Canvas etc. It is method to provide access from one LMS to another LMS, so that portals can share their contents. In short, If one LMS named A (LTI Consumer) want to read some study material from LMS B (LTI Provider) then A will launch a valid LTI request (Specification are provided by IMS Global) and B will validate the LTI & parse the data from request. Finally B will share its content. You can get details about LTI standard from [here](https://www.imsglobal.org/activity/learning-tools-interoperability).

Common cartridge is also provided by IMS Global. However, it is a format specification (XML) which is used to create exams, study materials etc. automatically. For example, if some one has an admin account in Blackboard LMS and he wants to share a course content to his Canvas LMS account. Then instead of creating each courses, exams or materials manually in Canvas LMS, he can easily export its course content from Blackboard LMS and then import it on Canvas LMS. Exported content should be in common cartridge format (.imscc). currently, common cartridge version 1.1.0 are widely popular. You can get details about common cartridge [here](http://www.imsglobal.org/cc/index.html) .